# DX10 Mesh::DrawSubSet

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm dabbling in DX11, and I noticed that there is no ID3DX11Mesh like there was a ID3DX10Mesh in DX10.
I imagine this could be due to one of two things, either ID3DX10Mesh did not neet replacing, since DX11 mostly just extends DX10, or it has been replaced by something in the XNA framework?

Not exactly a problem, the DX10 one still seems to work with DX11, but I thought I might as well implement my own mesh class.

Now the question is, how exactly does the ID3DX10Mesh::DrawSubSet work? Being able to draw subsets of a mesh with different materials/properties is something I expect I'll need.

I know it uses some kind of attribute table - I'm unclear though how this is stored and used.

A simple solution I can think of would be to simply store multiple index buffers in a mesh, one for each subset. With many properties though this could become a big number of index buffers.

Alternatively, by storing the mesh's faces (referencing vertices by index) and assigning properties to them, I could draw a subset of faces with a certain property by building an index buffer from all faces with that property.

Out of these two, storing the faces seems neater, but I expect I would have to store the index buffers anyway. (sacrificing time to rebuild these buffers every frame seems unnecessary)

I suppose many subsets should be avoided anyway to keep the number of draw calls low, and in that case the additional buffers should not take up too much additional memory.

Neither idea seems optimal though, so I'd welcome other ideas or clues to DrawSubSet's actual implementation :)

Comment: I completely forgot about the parameters of `ID3D11DeviceContext->DrawIndexed(UINT IndexCount, UINT StartIndexLocation, INT BaseVertexLocation)` which allow you to specify where to start and how many indices to process from the index buffer. So I would only need to organize my index buffer, and store the start and end of each subset's indices! This should make it a lot easier, and avoid uneccessary draw calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - forget about ID3DX__Mesh and implement your own class that has the functionality you require. They've removed it for the same reason they've removed *.x files support from DX10 - because despite the fact that MS had written in every corner of DX SDK that *.x file is just a dev/testing format and it's not suitable for production use, a lot of (apparently lazyor just ignorant) developers were using it, and sending complaints to MS about it's slowness/lack of some features. So MS has learnt the lesson.

Comment: That's why I was inquiring about the inner workings of DrawSubSet, so I could implement something like it. I'll need it to draw meshes that have subsets with different materials applied. As I said in my other comment, I think I can do all of that with DrawIndexed :)